# Is it possible to make a cmdlet work with all items being piped into it at once?

Tags: powershell, scripting

Instead of counting sheep this evening, I created a cmdlet that lists all duplicate files in a directory. It's dirt stupid simple and it can only work with *all* files in a directory, and I'm not keen on reinventing the wheel to add filtering, so here's what I want to do with it instead:

```
dir | duplicates | del
```

The only catch is that, normally, any given command in the pipe only works with one object at a time, which will do no good whatsoever for detecting duplicates. (Of course there are no duplicates in a set of one, right?)

Is there a trick I can use to have the second command in the chain collect all the output from the first before doing its job and passing things on to the third command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can work with a single file at a time, you just have to store each file you receive it the `Process` block and then process all the files in an `End` block.  This is how commands like Group &  Sort work.  They can't group or sort until they have all the input.  Once they have all the input, they do their operation and then begin streaming the results down the pipeline again in grouped/sorted order.

Comment: You did not mention the other possibility: just grab all the files in the `End` block already collected for you in `$input`, which would be slightly less code. So I was just curious, @Keith: did you omit that perhaps because it is less performant or just to keep your answer brief?

Comment: `$input` is fiddly.  While it would work fine as you've described it, if you for some reason where to add a `process` block later, `$input` in the `end` block would always be empty.

Comment: That is quite true but it is documented behavior... so by "fiddly" I assume you mean that you have the extra burden of having to be cognizant of what the rest of your function does to be able to know what $input will contain at a given moment, which is a fair point.

Answer (score 1):

So I actually came up with the answer while I was in the shower and came back to find Keith had already provided it. Here's an example anyway.

```
begin
{
    Add-Type -Path ($env:USERPROFILE + '\bin\CollectionHelper.cs');
    [string[]] $files = @()
}

process
{
    $files += $FullName
}

end
{
    [JMA.CollectionHelper]::Duplicates($files)
}
```